# Pytest: passing test variable or test file var to @pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on several custom loggers for pytest to improve the representation of test results as they are being executed. Presently for each iteration of the test I am able to capture test name, state and the parametrized blob. To be able to use custom logger on demand I would like to be able to turn it on per test file, per test or globally from the cli.

Presently when i look at the data in `@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)` the test file variables or test variables dont seem to be accessible.

Is there a way to pass specific variable(s) from test file, specific test within test file or globally from the cli to `@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)` for example: `(log_suite or log_test or cli_log) and log_file`?

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep) # for later use

    if rep.when == 'call':
        data = {'when': rep.when, 'outcome': rep.outcome, 'nodeid':rep.nodeid}

        # the reason loggin is here, as I would like to log every test permutation result as its happening.
        if (log_suite or log_test or cli_log) and log_file: # somehow to get those
            # log logic
```

**test_file.py**

```
import pytest 

log_suite = True
log_file = '/tmp/pytest.log'

@pytest.mark.parametrize('t_params', {300_permutations})
def test_permutations(t_params):
    log_test = True

    # some test logic ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access module-level variables in hooks via `item.module`, e.g.

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    yield
    log_file = item.module.log_file
    log_suite = item.module.log_suite
    ...
```

etc. You won't be able to access variables from function local scope though, they're already gone by that time. You can assign them to a module yourself, e.g. to `pytest`:

```
def test_permutations(t_params):
    pytest.log_test = True

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    yield
    log_test = pytest.log_test
```

or to your current test module:

```
def test_permutations(t_params):
    globals()['log_test'] = True

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    yield
    log_test = item.module.log_test
```

or use anything that's defined globally, for example, the cache:

```
def test_permutations(t_params, request):
    log_test = True
    request.config.cache.set('log_test', log_test)

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    yield
    log_test = item.session.config.cache.get('log_test', None)
```

BTW there's no such hook as `pytest_runtest_logger`, double-check that name or the tests won't be runnable. Here's the [reference of all hooks available](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#hooks).

Comment: ty it worked, i have updated pytest hook to in my original question

Comment: i have later switched to custom pytest marks instead, just to have a more clean approach without too may global or cashed variables